# Otimizar query. O foreach está muito lento

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho essa query

```
[Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<MarkupListResponse>))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int resellerId)
    {
        var catalogs = _catalogService.GetAllByResellerId(resellerId);
        var model = new List<MarkupListResponse>();

        foreach (var catalog in catalogs)
        {
            model.Add(new MarkupListResponse()
            {
                CreatedOn = catalog.CatalogDate,
                CatalogId = catalog.Id,
                ItemsQuantity = catalog.Items.Count
            });
        }

        return Ok(model);
    }
```

Em catalogs eu tenho 419 registros(Catálogos) cada catálogo, pode ter de 1 a 100 produtos. Quando entro no foreach, fica lento demais e cada iteração, ele monta um select semelhante a esse

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ResellerCatalogId] AS [ResellerCatalogId], 
    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
    [Extent1].[MarkupPercentual] AS [MarkupPercentual], 
    [Extent1].[MarkupFixed] AS [MarkupFixed], 
    [Extent1].[PriceSale] AS [PriceSale], 
    [Extent1].[EffectivePrice] AS [EffectivePrice]
    FROM [dbo].[ResellerCatalogItem] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ResellerCatalogId] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

Onde o parâmetro `@EntityKeyValue1` é o ID do catálogo(419 ao todo). A questão é melhorar isso tudo e já fiz algumas tentativas, tais como `lambda` em lugar de `foreach` e mesmo assim não resolveu. Gostaria de saber se tem como melhorar a performance disso.

Fazendo isso, melhorou bastante, mas não sei se existe uma outra forma mais performática

```
var qry = catalogs.Select(x => new MarkupListResponse
            {
                CreatedOn = x.CatalogDate,
                CatalogId = x.Id,
                ItemsQuantity = x.Items.Count
            });

            model.AddRange(qry);
```

Comment: Em que momento ocorre o SaveChanges?

Comment: Se puder poste seus modelos.

Comment: Tem certeza que a lentidão está no foreach?
Não entendi por quê ele monta um select a cada iteração, se o resultado da consulta já veio na chamada do service.

Comment: Se está lento faz a SQL não mão, executa em uma `View` com `FromSQL` e seja feliz, ou então faz um `Linq` objetivo mais ou menos assim `_catalogService.Select(x => new MarkupListResponse(){ CreatedOn  = x.CatalogDate, CatalogId = x.Id,  ItemsQuantity = x.Items.Count()}).ToList()`

Comment: Faça um teste removendo a linha `catalog.Items.Count` e avise se teve muita diferença

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves, comentei o Count e deu o mesmo resultado em tempo. Fiz uma edição, colocando o novo código e obtive um resultado mais performático. Creio, que quando for publicado, sem a influência do Debug, acredito que vai melhorar ainda mais. Esse site, tem muitos pontos de gargalo e não posso alterar muita coisa, tipo criar proc como sugerido por alguém, isso não dá para fazer.

Comment: Ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Veja como criar um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) para utilizar na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente quando você utiliza `x.Items.Count` o `Lazy Loading` faz uma consulta completa (SELECT * FROM ...) e então usa o `Linq` para a fazer a contagem de registros, por isso a lentidão.

Uma alternativa é usar uma proc para obter a contagem, seria mais eficiente.
Ou então utilizar o `IQueryable`, que coloca os comandos "linq" na query que será enviada no comando SQL ao invés de obter o restultado da query para depois filtrar.

## Exemplo:

O comando abaixo:

```
IQueryable<SalesPerson> top10SalesByBonusQueryable = 
   context.SalesPersons.OrderByDescending(p => p.Bonus).Take(10);
```

é equivalente a esta query:

```
SELECT TOP (10)
...
FROM [Sales].[SalesPerson] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Bonus] DESC
```

Segue abaixo um link útil:

[IEnumerable VS IQueryable](http://www.macoratti.net/14/11/net_ieiq1.htm)